# Connect to Ubuntu VM via SSH in C#

Tags: c#, linux, azure, ssh

I am trying to connect to an Azure Linux vm via SSH in C# using SSH.NET.

```
using (var client = new SshClient("my-vm.cloudapp.net", 22, "username", "password​"))
        {
            client.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("it worked!");
            client.Disconnect();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

However, I am getting the following exception:

```
No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication
```

I am able to to ssh in using these credentials in git bash and Putty, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means your server reject this method to connect. Usually SSH server only allow public key auth or other two factor auth.

Change your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`uncomment `#PasswordAuthentication yes`

```
 # Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
 #PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: I've checked the sshd_config, and that's already set to #PasswordAuthentication yes. Are there any other config settings that could be causing this?

Comment: uncomment it, remove the hastag so it will become `PasswordAuthentication yes`

Comment: don't forget to accept this as answer if it works so it will also help people that have the same problem